# as3 align texts horizontally

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

is any other way to align dynamic texts pulled out from a xml data and inserted into a text field?

here is my code

```
for(var j:int = 0; j < grad_data.length; j++)
{
    var textContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();
    var name_btn:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

    var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat("Trajan Pro", 14, 0xffffff, "bold");

    var textField:TextField = new TextField();
    textField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
    textField.defaultTextFormat = format;
    textField.text = grad_data[j].name;
    textField.width = textField.textWidth;

    textContainer.name = "grad_" + j;
    textContainer.addChild(textField);

    textContainer.buttonMode = true;
    textContainer.mouseChildren = false;

    textContainer.x = text_container.numChildren * textContainer.width;
            //textContainer.x = text_container.numChildren * 300;

    text_container.addChild(textContainer);

}
```

I already have tried using fix number (300).. and it seems to work fine except it is not dynamic.. but when i tried to get the width.. i did not do what i expect,

my design output is simply the one below.

```
dynamic text 1  dynamic text longer    dynamic text short
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to align text in textField to be in middle then use this Option

use the Property `textField.verticalAlign = VerticalAlign.MIDDLE;`

if you want to align all element of text_container to be in middle then use this Option

align all element of text_container by setting `text_container.verticalAlign = VerticalAlign.MIDDLE;`

if you want to align all element of textContainer to be in middle then use `textContainer.verticalAlign = VerticalAlign.MIDDLE;`

i give this answer because i don't know structure of it

may this will help you